# Removing : from dateTime object, proper regex for this?

Tags: javascript, regex, datetime

I am using the dateTime creation of a folder and would like to use that as part of the folder name.  This has ":" characters in it though and I am having a hard time finding the correct regular expression to filter out the ":".  For example, the dateTime output is "Wed May 20 20:16:42 CDT 2015" and I would like it to be "Wed May 20 201642 CDT 2015"

I have the following

```
var fso, fo, dc;
fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
fo = fso.GetFolder("C:\\examplefolder");
dc = fo.DateCreated; //this gives me "Wed May 20 20:16:42 CDT 2015"
dc = dc.replace(/:/g, "");
```

That doesn't get the : out of the datetime and I get an error.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `fo.DateCreated` is a date object which does not have the `replace` method.

```
//use one of the appropriate methods from toString(), toLocaleString(), toUTCString() etc to get a string representation
dc = new Date(fo.DateCreated).toString(); //a workaround since dc.toString() is not working
dc = dc.replace(/:/g, "");
```

Note: Haven't worked with ActiveX before, so don't why `dc.toString()` is not working.

Comment: thanks for the detailed response.  When i run the toString() I am now getting an error that an Object is expected.  My understanding is that toString() and toUTCString don't need any arguments

Comment: thanks, that works, except for i needed to use dc.replace(/\:/g, "") instead to remove the :